# Symfony Login with username OR email

Tags: php, symfony

I would like users to be able to log in with their e-mail address or username.
How and where can I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

The better way is to do that (according to the Symfony doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user))  :

```
// src/Repository/UserRepository.php
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;

class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    // ...

    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $usernameOrEmail): ?User
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

        return $entityManager->createQuery(
                'SELECT u
                FROM App\Entity\User u
                WHERE u.username = :query
                OR u.email = :query'
            )
            ->setParameter('query', $usernameOrEmail)
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

Note that the implementation `implements UserLoaderInterface` and its `loadUserByIdentifier()` method are required!

To finish this, remove the property key from the user provider in security.yaml:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    providers:
        users:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but where do I have to call the function loadUserByIdentifier?

Comment: Fatal error: Class App\Repository\UserRepository contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface::loadUserByUsername) in /home/luis/PhpstormProjects/overtime_new/code/src/Repository/UserRepository.php on line 22

Comment: @Luu If you make the inequality of the code sent (and which is also in the doc I provided you the link ;) ) the method loadUserByIdentifier is automatically called by Symfony, no worries ;) For the error, have you implemented everything correctly in your UserRepository ?